# compare two excel files using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

1. I want to compare two excel files using javascript
   comparing two excels getting some error
   2.i want to compare 2 different columns present in two different files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json to convert those excel files to JSON and then write the necessary logic for comparing both resulting JSONs

Comment: var excel_compare = require("excel-compare");

excel_compare({
    File1:'trial/book1.xlsx',
    File2:'trial/neww.xlsx',
    column_file1: {
        column: ['1'],
        join:''
    },
column_file2: {
    column: ['1', '2'],
    join: '-'
}
})
 its showing error

Comment: npm install convert-excel-to-json 
First convert the excel file to JSON and write your JavaScript logic to compare them. The code to covert the Excel to JSON is below,
const excelToJson = require('convert-excel-to-json');

 const result = excelToJson({
    sourceFile: 'SOME-EXCEL-FILE.xlsx'
});

Comment: after converting what is way to compare converted json

Comment: You will be getting a javascript object like:  
{
    sheet1: [{
        A: 'data of cell A1',
        B: 'data of cell B1',
        C: 'data of cell C1'
    }],
    sheet2: [{
        A: 'data of cell A1',
        B: 'data of cell B1',
        C: 'data of cell C1'
    }]
}

You can compare the object by writing your own logic.

Comment: If you find the idea helpful, please upvote.